# Flask : url_for with <a> tag doesn't get rendered in browser

Tags: python, flask

here is my template code (**menu.html**) :

```
<html>

<body>

<h1>{{restaurant.name}}</h1>


{% for i in items %}

<div>

<p>{{i.name}}</p>

<p>{{i.description}}</p>

<p> {{i.price}} </p>

<a href='{{url_for('editMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id, menu_id = i.id) }}'>Edit</a>

</br>
<a href = '{{url_for('deleteMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id, menu_id = i.id ) }}'>Delete</a>

</div>


{% endfor %}
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my code where I invoke the `render_template()` function :

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/')
def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id):
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id=restaurant.id)
    return render_template('menu.html',restaurant=restaurant,items=items)
```

The import :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
```

---

My **problem** is that my **`Edit`** and **`Delete`** anchor tags don't get rendered at all! Why is that so ?

Here is a look at the DOM :
[image]

**EDIT:1**
In fact whatever changes I make in the `menu.html` do not get changed at all ! Even if it as simple as adding a static text into it.

Comment: Are you sure  you don't have two copies of `menu.html`? Possibly in another folder?

Comment: I don't know Flask, but try changing the outer single-quotes to double-quotes. `<a href="{{url_for('editMenuItem', ... }}">Edit</a>`

Comment: @PM2Ring : I guess that was the problem! Double quotes were needed! Please answer the question, I will mark it as *answer*

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Ok, although I feel like an [impostor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) answering a Flask question. :)

Comment: I've just been informed that my answer does _not_ fix your real problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring: What is the problem!? Actually it may have been coincidental that it solved my problem. But the real problem may have been something different

Comment: @PM2Ring: Did you come to know what the real problem is ?

Comment: As I said before, I don't know Flask, but apparently your problem has something to do with not reloading templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use single-quotes inside a single-quoted string. You *might* be able to get around that by using backslash-escaped quotes: `\'`. But a simpler way is to just change the outer quotes to double-quotes, i.e., change

```
<a href='{{url_for('editMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id,
    menu_id = i.id) }}'>Edit</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{url_for('editMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id,
    menu_id = i.id) }}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Thank You! I will try to use the escape literal too!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code in template?

```
<a href='{{url_for('editMenuItem', restaurant_id=restaurant.id, menu_id=items.id) }}'>Edit</a>

</br>

<a href = '{{url_for('deleteMenuItem', restaurant_id=restaurant.id, menu_id=items.id) }}'>Delete</a>
```

Instead of providing `i` (`i.id`) in the template, there should be `items` (`items.id`), because that is the name of parameter in backend code (`render_template('menu.html',restaurant=restaurant,items=items)`).

About all the changes in template, maybe you need to clear cache or use `Ctrl + Shift + R` keyboard combination?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry.. I did not add the complete code of `menu.html`.. But please see the updated code. I have a `for` loop where in I define the variable `i`

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh It's ok, I didn't see it until now. Good work PM 2Ring.